# Laravel MariaDB errno:150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb, laravel-5.3

my posts migration is :

```
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('channel_id');
        $table->foreign('channel_id')->references('id')->on('channels');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->string('status')->default('published');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('published_at');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and channels :

```
        Schema::create('channels', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('channel_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

now , when I executed `php artisan migrate` the following error message showed up :

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `TBL_NAME`.`#sql-
  2221_1f76c` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQ
  L: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_channel_id_foreign` foreign ke
  y (`channel_id`) references `channels` (`id`))


  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `TBL_NAME`.`#sql-
  2221_1f76c` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and thats migrations works perfectly on my local computer that I use MySQL on it. but when I upload my Laravel project on the server and I using MariaDB on the server. I see that error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `posts` table migration change this:

```
$table->string('channel_id');
```

To this:

```
$table->integer('channel_id')->unsigned();
```

Also, make sure you run `channels` table migration before `posts` table migration.

Comment: @unbl0ck3r it can be more effective to create migrations to setup all of the tables first and then a set of migrations for foreign keys.